# Is women's tennis the only sport which is shorter than men?

Tags: rules, tennis, international-sports, performance, gender

Women's soccer is played for 2 halves at 45 minutes with 15 minute break in between, just like men https://yoursoccerhome.com/how-long-is-a-womens-soccer-game/

Yet, men have to play best of 5 sets in tennis, whereas women play best of 3. Is this the only sport which has less stamina requirements for women?

Comment: The "why" part is covered by [this duplicate](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/what-is-the-reason-men-play-5-sets-women-play-3-sets-in-a-grand-slam-in-tennis) so I'll remove that bit from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, lots of sports have different rules related to timing, though I'd note that it's unclear how much this is due to stamina versus money/historical interest.  Stamina is not straightforward question between men and women (see: extreme long distance running, women hold the records, not men).

Softball is [7 innings](https://www.teamusa.org/-/media/USA_Softball/Documents/2020/USA-2020-Rulebook.pdf?la=en&hash=D84E07B841E1A108FC2BF269434C7854DCB57526) versus baseball being [9 innings](https://content.mlb.com/documents/2/2/4/305750224/2019_Official_Baseball_Rules_FINAL_.pdf).

[WNBA periods are 10 minutes, 40 minute games](https://ak-static.cms.nba.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/27/2022/05/2022-WNBA-RULE-BOOK-FINAL.pdf) while [NBA periods are 12 minutes, 48 minute games](https://official.nba.com/rule-no-5-scoring-and-timing/).

Golf could be another one here - while the "length" of the game is the same, moving the tees forward makes it a shorter game (or rather, aims to make it the same length-of-time instead of longer).

Comment: I'd say the basketball one is more the NBA being anomalous - FIBA rules are 4x10 minutes for men as well.

Comment: @PhilipKendall It is, nonetheless, an example of men's and women's sports being different at the same level :). Tennis in fact is not different there either - ATP is 3 sets for both, and ITF does not differentiate men/women in allowing 3 or 5 sets.

Comment: (And yes, I know baseball and softball are technically different sports, and men can play softball - player here! - but at the professional level, for historical reasons, softball is "girls baseball".)

Answer (score 4):

In athletics:

- The women run [100m hurdles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_metres_hurdles) while the men run [110m hurdles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/110_metres_hurdles); the hurdles are also lower for women than men.

  - While men and women both run [400m hurdles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/400_metres_hurdles), the hurdles are again lower for women.
- The [discus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discus_throw#Regulations),  [javelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javelin_throw#Weight_rules_by_age_group) and [shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_put#Weight) are all lighter for women than for men.
- The women's multi-discipline event has [7 events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptathlon) while the men's has [10 events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decathlon).